# How do I create a regular expression for this in android?

Tags: java, android, regex

Suppose I have a string like this:

```
string = "Manoj Kumar Kashyap";
```

Now I want to create a regular expression to match where Ka appears after space and also want to get index of matching characters.

I am using java language.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use regular expressions just like in Java SE:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".* (Ka).*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("Manoj Kumar Kashyap");
if(matcher.matches())
{
    int idx = matcher.start(1);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a regular expression to do that. I'm not a Java expert, but according to the [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html):

> **public int  indexOf  (String string)**
>   Searches in this string for the first
>   index of the specified string. The
>   search for the string starts at the
>   beginning and moves towards the end of
>   this string.
>
> **Parameters**
> string  the string to find.
>
> **Returns**
>  the index of the first
>   character of the specified string in
>   this string, -1 if the specified
>   string is not a substring.

You'll probably end up with something like:

```
int index = somestring.indexOf(" Ka");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need regular expressions and not just `indexOf`, it's possible to do it like this

```
String[] split = "Manoj Kumar Kashyap".split("\\sKa");
if (split.length > 0)
{
    // there was at least one match
    int startIndex = split[0].length() + 1;
}
```