# check the ascii code for arabic letters and showing an error message?

Tags: if-statement, for-loop, ascii, message, arabic

***i want to check the text if it was arabic show the letter 
in the other text 
if it is for example was english or korean 
 show the error message saying enter an arabic text 
but it shows the error message both ways if i write arabic or english  or any other language 
and iam 100% sure about the letters  i entered on the 
text matches the ascii on the if statment 
 so what iam i doing wrong ??!!!***

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
EditText te1;
EditText te2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    te1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.t1);
    te2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.t2);

final AlertDialog ad;
    ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    ad.setTitle("رسالة خطأ");
    ad.setMessage("رجاء  ادخل نص عربي  ");
    ad.setButton("موافق^_*", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             dialog.dismiss(); 
        }

    });



    final Button v = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
    v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // imva.setImageResource(R.id.b1);






            for ( int j = 0 ; j < te1.length() ; j++)
            {
            String l =  te1.toString();
      char coverLetter =l.charAt(j);    

 if ((coverLetter >= 1569) && (coverLetter <= 1594) || (coverLetter >= 1600) && (coverLetter<= 1610))

      {     
          te2.setText("غ ");

      }
      else 
        {

            ad.show();
        }

        }// for 
        } 
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

To check for Arabic text, you can use regular expressions:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

bool isArabic = Regex.IsMatch(text,@"[\p{IsArabic}]+");
```

To account for spaces in between text:

```
bool isArabic = Regex.IsMatch(text,@"[\p{IsArabic}\s]+");
```

Comment: Can't you use the same Regexes on Android?

Comment: @ Jerry i tryed but it keeps giving me error on  this line       using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

Comment: @ Jerry i found a way and it worked thank you for answering me

Comment: I'm glad it worked. Anyway here is a link for regexes for Android: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129996/how-do-i-create-a-regular-expression-for-this-in-android